# jQuery / SQLite to save what the user enters in text area

Tags: sqlite, cordova

The following is the JavaScript I am including with my mobile application

```
document.addEventListener( "deviceready", onDeviceReady, false );

$currentstatusview = $('#currentstatusview'); queryresult = "haha";

function onDeviceReady( ) 
{

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase( { name: "custombase.db" } );
db.transaction( getTableReady );

}

// Create table if the table does not exist
//
function getTableReady(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
                     CUSTOMTABLE (word unique, meaning)' );
}

// Insert A New Row
//
function insertNewLine(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql(necessarysqlstatement);
}

// Query the database
//
function viewthelastglory(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql( 'SELECT * FROM CUSTOMTABLE', [], querySuccess, errorCB );
}

// Query the success callback
// 
function querySuccess(tx, results) 
{

for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
{
    queryresult =+ "<br>Row " + i + " Word : " + results.rows.item(i).word + " Meaning     : " + results.rows.item(i).meaning;
}

$currentstatusview.text(queryresult);

}

function errorCB(err) 
{
   alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}
```

and then in the html

```
<div id=currentstatusview> </div>
```

But nothing pops up in the html element currentstatusview above.

My Cordova is 3.5.0-0.2.7 and I installed the SQLite plugin using the command below

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```

Comment: what is the error that is being shown? As I can see the variable `var db` is local to the `onDeviceReady()` function, it will not be available to the `insertNewLine and viewthelastglory` functions. You need to define it in the global context. i.e either `db = ...` or `window.db = ...`

Comment: Frank, your advice was awesome, old pal. My SQLite is working gracefully now eh

Comment: Your welcome. I have added it as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see the variable `var db` is local to the `onDeviceReady()` function.
It will not be available to the `insertNewLine and viewthelastglory` functions.
You need to define it in the global context. i.e either `db = ...` or `window.db = ...`
Both definitions are the same.
Preferably use `window.db = ...` as it **explicitly** states it as a global declaration.